# Why is the Hartree-Fock energy the sum of zeroth and first order energies?

Tags: condensed-matter, perturbation-theory

For $H$ the exact Hamiltonian to the Schrodinger equation, $H_{0}$ the Hartree-Fock Hamiltonian, $\lambda$ the dimensionless parameter that controls perturbation term $V$:

The exact Hamiltonian to the Schrodinger equation can be expressed in terms of the Hartree-Fock Hamiltonian as
$$H = H_{0} + \lambda V.$$
With some algebra, it can be shown that the ground state zeroth order $MP_{0}$, ground state first order $MP_{1}$, and ground state second order $MP_{2}$ energies are
$$E^{(0)} = \langle \psi_{0}|H_{0}|\psi_{0}\rangle$$
$$E^{(1)} = \langle \psi_{0}|V|\psi_{0}\rangle$$
$$E^{(2)} = \langle \psi_{0}|V|\psi^{(1)}\rangle,$$
where $\psi_{0}$ is the zeroth-order Hartree-Fock wave function.

How do I reason from above physically that the ground state Hartree - Fock energy $E_{0} = \langle \psi_{0}|H_{0} + V| \psi_{0}\rangle$? Why not add second order and so on?
This is the sum of the zeroth and first order Hartree - Fock ground state energies and had the Hartree - Fock energy been exact, the Hartree - Fock energy would equal that of the energy solution to the Schrodinger equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a trivial observation. The energy accurate up to first order is always the expectation value of the full Hamiltonian with the zeroth-order wave function:
$$
E^{(0)}+E^{(1)}=
\langle\Psi^{(0)}|\hat{H}^{(0)}+\hat{V}|\Psi^{(0)}\rangle=
\langle\Psi^{(0)}|\hat{H}|\Psi^{(0)}\rangle \ .
$$
You can think of this as calculating an approximate energy with a trial function (that happens to be $|\Psi^{(0)}\rangle$).

By definition, the Hartree-Fock energy is the minimum value of the functional
$$
E_{\text{det}}[\phi_1,...,\phi_N]=\langle\Phi|\hat{H}|\Phi\rangle \ ,
$$
where
$\{\phi_i\}$ are orbitals building up the Slater determinant $|\Phi\rangle$:
$$
E_{\text{HF}}=\min_{\phi_1,...\phi_N} E_{\text{det}}[\phi_1,...,\phi_N]
=E_{\text{det}}[\phi^{\text{HF}}_1,...,\phi^{\text{HF}}_N]
=\langle\Phi_{\text{HF}}|\hat{H}|\Phi_{\text{HF}}\rangle
 \ .
$$
So, if you find an operator $\hat{f}$ whose eigenfunctions happen to be $\{\phi^{\text{HF}}_i\}$:
$$
\hat{f}\phi^{\text{HF}}_i=\varepsilon^{\text{HF}}_i\phi^{\text{HF}}_i \ ,
$$
so that
$$
\hat{F}|\Phi_{\text{HF}}\rangle=
\sum_{i=1}^N\hat{f}_i|\Phi_{\text{HF}}\rangle
=\sum_{i=1}^N\varepsilon^{\text{HF}}_i|\Phi_{\text{HF}}\rangle \ ,
$$
and you use this $\hat{F}$ to define a PT partitioning of the Hamiltonian:
$$
\hat{H}=\hat{F}+(\hat{H}-\hat{F})=\hat{F}+\hat{W} \ ,
$$
then the energy up to first order will be the HF energy by construction:
$$
E_{\text{MP}}^{(0)}+E_{\text{MP}}^{(1)}=
\sum_{i=1}^N\varepsilon^{\text{HF}}_i+
\langle\Phi_{\text{HF}}|\hat{W}|\Phi_{\text{HF}}\rangle
=E_{\text{HF}} \ .
$$
I am not sure how much physical picture can be put behind this, other than the fact that the sum of HF orbital energies doublecounts the electron-electron interaction, which is compensated by the first-order term:
$$
\varepsilon^{\text{HF}}_i=\langle\phi^{\text{HF}}_i|\hat{h}|\phi^{\text{HF}}_i\rangle+\sum_{j=1}^{N}\langle\phi^{\text{HF}}_i\phi^{\text{HF}}_j|\hat{V}(1-P_{12})|\phi^{\text{HF}}_i\phi^{\text{HF}}_j\rangle\ ,
$$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\varepsilon^{\text{HF}}_i=
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\langle\phi^{\text{HF}}_i|\hat{h}|\phi^{\text{HF}}_i\rangle+
\sum_{i,j=1}^{N}\langle\phi^{\text{HF}}_i\phi^{\text{HF}}_j|\hat{V}(1-P_{12})|\phi^{\text{HF}}_i\phi^{\text{HF}}_j\rangle
\ ,
$$
$$
\langle\Phi_{\text{HF}}|\hat{W}|\Phi_{\text{HF}}\rangle=
-\frac{1}{2}
\sum_{i,j=1}^{N}\langle\phi^{\text{HF}}_i\phi^{\text{HF}}_j|\hat{V}(1-P_{12})|\phi^{\text{HF}}_i\phi^{\text{HF}}_j\rangle 
\ ,
$$
so indeed
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\varepsilon^{\text{HF}}_i+
\langle\Phi_{\text{HF}}|\hat{W}|\Phi_{\text{HF}}\rangle
&=
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\langle\phi^{\text{HF}}_i|\hat{h}|\phi^{\text{HF}}_i\rangle+
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^{N}\langle\phi^{\text{HF}}_i\phi^{\text{HF}}_j|\hat{V}(1-P_{12})|\phi^{\text{HF}}_i\phi^{\text{HF}}_j\rangle
\\
&=
E_{\text{HF}} \ .
\end{aligned}
$$